# Having Multiple Modals per page

Tags: javascript, html, web, bootstrap-modal

I'm creating a website where the user can click on an image to open a modal with menu items within, while the first modal works fine, subsequent modals do not.

JS Code:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myImg");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML where its used:

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Starters</h2>
        <img src="http://foodnetwork.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2007/2/9/0/ie0102_coleslaw.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" id="myImg">
                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                  <!-- Modal content -->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <span class="close">×</span>
                      <br>
                      <h2>Starters</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p><b>PRODUCT <span style="display:inline-block; width: 75%;"></span> PRICE</b></p>
                      <hr>
                      <p> Humus <span style="display:inline-block; width: 78%;"></span>  £3.00</p>
                      <p> Dolma <span style="display:inline-block; width: 78%;"></span>  £3.20</p>
                      <p> Coleslaw <span style="display:inline-block; width: 77%;"></span>  £1.50</p>
                      <p> Prawn Cocktail <span style="display:inline-block; width: 73.5%;"></span>  £4.60</p>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Wraps</h2>
        <img src="http://harryskebabs.com/images/demo/menu-main/menu-item-large-20.jpg" height="100%" width="100%" id="myImg">

                <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                  <!-- Modal content -->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <span class="close">×</span>
                      <br>
                      <h2>Starters</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p><b>PRODUCT <span style="display:inline-block; width: 75%;"></span> PRICE</b></p>
                      <hr>
                      <p> Chicken Wrap <span style="display:inline-block; width: 78%;"></span>  £3.00</p>
                      <p> Doner Wrap <span style="display:inline-block; width: 78%;"></span>  £3.20</p>
                      <p> Shish Wrap <span style="display:inline-block; width: 77%;"></span>  £1.50</p>
                      <p> Kofte Wrap <span style="display:inline-block; width: 73.5%;"></span>  £4.60</p>
                    </div>

                  </div>

                </div>

    </div>
```

The first modal box shown will work as expected, while the second will not show at all, i would rather not have to unnecessarily replicate JavaScript if i don't have to, which is why i tired this method.

Very new to JS and modal boxes, so any input would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `modal` in `modal.style.display = none` refers to an element with the id of "Modal". You have two elements which have this *but* `id`s given to HTML elements need to *unique*.

This goes for all `id`s, so you'll have to change give your images unique ids too.

Comment: So is the fix to simply rename the "modal.style.display = none" to "modal2.style.display = none" and then make changes to reflect that?

Comment: Answer amended. What you need to do is rename your ids so that there are no duplicates. So myModal0, myModal1 and myImg0 and myImg1. Then you can modify you event handles to close/open the appropriate modal depending on the name's number suffix.

Comment: would i need to declare a new variable in JS so mymodal1= getelementbyid("modal1") etc? and then redo my js accordingly? because i just tried that and now the modal will work on the image, so ty for help on that front. but now the modal will still open with the "starter" content instead of the "wraps" content. If it would be helpful i can supply a pastebin of the file.

Comment: Found the issue, forgot to change a snippet of code to reflect the changes, thanks for help.

Comment: Glad you  resolved your issue. If you found my answer helpful, marking it as accepted would be greatly appreciated.